# How to only select observations in common to both dataframes in a merged dataframe?

Tags: r

I have merged data set 1 (3346 observations) and data set 2 (10000 observations) by 2 common columns using:

```
new_dataset=inner_join (dataset1,dataset2, by=c("name1","name2"))
```

and I ended up with a new dataset of 4501 observations. Both datasets are answers to surveys and the `dataset1` had weight applied to the sample so in oder to analyse it, I need to maintain the sample size of 3346 observations. I don't know how to only select the right 3346 observations (the ones that are in common to both datasets) from the 4501 observations of my new dataset. Thanks for any help provided

Comment: It sounds to me that you're after a `left_join` instead of an `inner_join`. I.e. `left_join(dataset1, dataset2, by = c("name1","name2"))`

Comment: or rathe ritz's sounds that `name1` and/or `name2` are not unique. There are more than one match of `dataset1:name1` to `dataset2:name2`?

Comment: Thanks Maurits, the left_join gives even a bigger number

Comment: Thanks, stephen. It is possible indeed, how do I fix this?

Comment: @zineb Its a feature not a fault. You can only "fix" it if your data has a unique key column that matches singly to dataset2 or a combination of such key columns?